# Disable hyperlink warnings in Microsoft Office 2003

Tags: microsoft-office-2003

Can I prevent Microsoft office from displaying local hyperlink warnings. 
I have created DWORD=DisableHyperlinkWarning and I have set value to 1.
I have also done the same to Policies.
The warnings are still there.
I am using Access 2003

Comment: Access 2003 has been out of support for 5 years. I don't think you will have much luck asking for help about something which is so old

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your settings, when you click on a hyperlink in a document, Micorosoft Office might display a warning. When you click on, say, a picture linked to an executable, Office will almost certainly display a warning.

You might want to disable these messages, since we’re assuming you know what you’re doing. These warnings happen only in Office 2003, so the following is applicable
only to that version.

Click **Start**

Click **Run**

Type regedit in the Open input box and hit Enter key
Navigate to:
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Common**

Here you should find a key called Security. Create it if it’s not there. Select the newly-created key, and there, create a DWORD called DisableHyperlinkWarning, and set it to **1**, of course, to disable the warning messages.

You also need to navigate to:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Common**

And repeat Step 5 above — find or create a key called Security, and the DWORD Value. Set it to the same value (0 or 1) as you did in the previous entry. Start or restart any Office program to see the chang